# Any good way of returning the max depth of a nested hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

The Hash object looks as follows, it has both array and hash values, but the nest always happens at the value for the "children" array:

```
a = {"id" => "1", "children" => [{"id"=>"11", "children"=>[{"id"=>"111"}]}, {"id"=>"12", "children"=>[{"id"=>"121", "children"=>[{"id"=>"1211"}]}, {"id"=>"122"}]}]}
a.max_depth = 3
```

Comment: What if you have nested arrays as values? How deep is it when you wrap hashes inside an array? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The following (non-recursive) instance method `Hash#depth` returns the desired measure of depth. I've add a `puts` statement to display the intermediate calculations.

```
class Hash
  def depth
    arr = values
    d = 0
    loop do
      arr = arr.flatten.select { |e| e.is_a? Hash }
      break d if arr.empty?
      d += 1
      arr = arr.map(&:values)
      puts "d = #{d}, arr = #{arr}"
    end
  end
end

a.depth
d = 1, arr = [["11", [{"id"=>"111"}]], ["12", [{"id"=>"121", "children"=>
                [{"id"=>"1211"}]}, {"id"=>"122"}]]]
d = 2, arr = [["111"], ["121", [{"id"=>"1211"}]], ["122"]]
d = 3, arr = [["1211"]]
  #=> 3
```

Answer (score -1):

This will find the depth of any nested hash, also traversing arrays and assigning them a depth of zero.

```
class Hash
  def max_depth
    1 + values.map do |val| 
      if val.respond_to?(:max_depth) 
        val.max_depth
      elsif val.respond_to?(:max)
        val.max { |elt| elt.max_depth }
      else
        0
      end
    end.max
  end
end
```

Comment: Fair enough.  Done.  Thanks.

Comment: You could simply replace `values.map` with `each_value.map` on the first version

Comment: I modified the example to replace `.map{ … }.max` with simply `.max{ … }`, since [`max` can take a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max).

Comment: Please look over your code: ` a.max_depth #=> ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with 0 failed`, where `a` iis the OP's hash.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for your case:

```
def array_traverse(array, depth)
  array.each do |i|
    if i.class == Array
      depth = array_traverse(i, depth)
    elsif i.class == Hash
      depth = hash_traverse(i, depth)
    end
  end
  return depth
end

def hash_traverse(hash, depth)
  hash.keys().each do |i|
    depth += 1 if i == 'children' and hash[i].length > 1
    if hash[i].class == Array
      depth = array_traverse(hash[i], depth)
    elsif hash[i].class == Hash
      depth = hash_traverse(hash[i], depth)
    end
  end
  return depth
end

puts hash_traverse(a, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are specifically trying to find the depth of the "children" key you can use this approach:

```
class Hash
  def max_depth
    max_depth = 1
    depth_func = ->(hsh, cur_depth) do
      max_depth = cur_depth if cur_depth > max_depth
      hsh["children"].to_a.each{|h| depth_func.call(h, cur_depth+1)}
      max_depth
    end
    depth_func.call(self, 0)
  end
end
```

Now you can try the code:

```
h = {  "id" => "1", "children" => [{"id"=>"11", "children"=>[{"id"=>"111"}]}, 
       {"id"=>"12", "children"=>[{"id"=>"121", "children"=>[{"id"=>"1211"}]}, 
       {"id"=>"122"}]}]}

h.max_depth # 3
```

Comment: this does not return my depth either

Comment: @shigazaru It works with my sample. Can you provide the hash for which it didn't work.