# hash deep_merge with arrays

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I've searched through all the answers regarding the use of deep_merge; however, I am still having trouble with my particular issue.  I'm trying to merge 2 hashes and add a specific key for each match.  For example:

**UPDATED THE FORMAT**

Hash 1:

```
{
  "actions"=> [
    {
      "causes"=> [
        {
          "shortDescription"=>"short description for run 1", 
          "userId"=>"user.a"
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "artifacts"=> [], 
  "fullDisplayName"=>"Run #1", 
  "result"=>"FAILURE", 
  "changeSet"=> {
    "items"=>[], 
    "kind"=>nil
  }, 
  "culprits"=> []
}
```

Hash 2:

```
{
  "actions"=> [
    {
      "causes"=> [
        {
          "shortDescription"=>"short description for run 2", 
          "userId"=>"user.b"
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "artifacts"=> [], 
  "fullDisplayName"=>"Run #2", 
  "result"=>"FAILURE", 
  "changeSet"=> {
    "items"=>[], 
    "kind"=>nil
  }, 
  "culprits"=> []
}
```

Key list:

```
["key-one","key-two"]
```

I would like the resulting hash to be:

```
{
  "actions"=> [
    {
      "causes"=> [
        { 
          "shortDescription"=> {
            "key-one" => "short description for run 1", 
            "key-two" => "short description for run 2"
          }, 
          "userId"=> {
            "key-one" => "user.a", 
            "key-two" => "user.b"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "artifacts"=> {
    "key-one" => [], 
    "key-two" => []
  }, 
  "fullDisplayName"=> {
    "key-one" => "Run #1", 
    "key-two" => "Run #2"
  }, 
  "result"=> {
    "key-one" => "FAILURE", 
    "key-two" => "FAILURE"
  }, 
  "changeSet"=> {
    "items"=> {
      "key-one" => [], "key-two" => []
    }, 
    "kind"=> {
      "key-one" => nil, 
      "key-two" => nil
    }
  }, 
  "culprits"=> {
    "key-one" => [], 
    "key-two" => [] 
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should catch the `max_depth` of your hashes (as shown here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500070/any-good-way-of-returning-the-max-depth-of-a-nested-hash-in-ruby`) then inject the key list values there, and finally merge the arrays

Comment: @Newben - I'll try that approach tonight.  Thanks!

Comment: Being new to SO, you may want to look over [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `h1` and `h2` are the two hashes you wish to merge, and `h3` is the desired result, I think the following should work:

```
@merge_key1, @merge_key2 = "key-one", "key-two"

def merge_em(g1, g2)
  case g1
  when Array
    g1.size.times {|i| merge_em(g1[i], g2[i])}
  when Hash
    g1.keys.each do |k|
      v = g1[k]
      if (Hash === v || (Array === v && !v.empty?)) 
        merge_em(v, g2[k])
      else
        g1[k] = {@merge_key1 => v, @merge_key2 => g2[k]}
      end
    end
  end
end

h = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h1))
merge_em(h, h2)
p (h == h3) # => true
```

A few notes:

- This solution depends on the hash structures; it may not work if the structures are changed.
- `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h1))` is used to make a "deep copy" of `h1`, so that `h1` is not modified.  If `h1` can be modified, `merge_em(h1, h2)` is sufficient, with `h1` being the merged hash.
- The gem [awesome_print](http://rubygems.org/gems/awesome_print) gives you a nicely-formatted display of complex structures like these.  All you'd need to do here is `require 'ap'` followed by `ap h`.  Try it!